# Adding MySQL to Windows Terminal profiles

Tags: mysql, windows-terminal

I just started using the relatively new Windows Terminal, but while adding my profiles (Git, etc.) I stumbled upon a problem I couldn't add MySql.

Comment: simply add a new profile fpr mysql and the commandline "mysql.exe -u roo -p secretoassword" and then add the options you need

Comment: It gives me error: [error 0x80070002 when launching `mysql.exe -u roo -p *mypassword*']

Comment: try your command in a regular windows command and chelc it, it can be that you nee "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe" instead of only mysql.exe. when it start in windows command all is ok

Comment: it works now thanks, I used the full path "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\bin\\mysql.exe -u root -p ", but without the password

Answer (score 1):

Input text like this.

```
[SQL_PATH].exe "--defaults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" "-uroot" "-p" "--default-character-set=utf8mb4"
```

notice 1: never quote mysql.exe
notice 2: quote the command line options.